# RegExp sobre nombres compuestos

Tags: javascript, regex

necesito una expresión regular para validar nombres en un formulario. Debe de validar tanto nombres simples como compuestos, pero solo compuestos por dos palabras, José Manuel sería válido mientras "De La Rosa" no lo sería. También debe validar que la primera letra sea mayúscula y el resto minúscula, además de no tener ningún número.

Por último, el nombre, tanto simple como compuesto, no puede sobrepasar de 15 caracteres ni tener menos de tres.

La cadena construida es la siguiente:

```
var patronNombre = /^([A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}[a-zñáéíóú]+[\s]*)+$/;
```

Lo único que no consigo es configurar correctamente la longitud del texto.

Gracias.

Comment: Y por qué no iba a ser válido "De La Rosa"?

Comment: La expresión regular debe validar una cadena formada por nombres y apellidos? O solo el nombre?

Comment: De La Rosa no debe ser válido porque contiene dos espacios, al igual que tampoco sería válido "Miguel De Manuel". Es una práctica de clase, no tiene por qué ser lógica.

Comment: Solo debe validar nombre, nombre simple o nombre compuesto, ejemplos válidos: "Pepe", "José Manuel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóú]+(?: [A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóú]+)?$
```

Tienes una demo **[aquí](https://regex101.com/r/OMCTTX/1/)**.

**Explicación**:

```
^
    (?=.{3,15}$)    # Lookahead. Lo siguiente debe ser cualquier cosa
                    # entre 3 y 15 y luego fin de línea
    [A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóú]+    # Primera en mayúscula y luego 1 o más minúsculas
    (?: # Grupo
        [A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóú]+    # Primera en mayúscula y luego 1 o más minúsculas
    )?  # El grupo puede aparecer 0 o 1 vez
$
```

Comment: ¡Sí señor!, muchas gracias Julio, es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por la aclaración tan detallada, me es muy útil para aprender a componerla yo en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Tu expresión regular está bastante bien, pero le faltan algunas cosas. Aunque no soy un experto en expresiones regulares, he trabajado algún tiempo con ellas y tengo una forma de hacer la validación para este caso que planteas.

Usando lo que ya tienes en tu expresión regular lo vamos a complementar para que se ajuste al requerimiento.

Usaremos una validación previa para verificar el tamaño del `string` de tal manera que tenga máximo 15 caracteres.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea validar un campo `input` de texto, de tal manera que permita solamente lo siguiente:

1. Una o dos palabras
2. La primera letra de cada palabra (si hubiera 2) debe estar en mayúscula y el resto en minúsculas.
3. Las palabras solo estarán separadas por un espacio simple
4. Las palabras solo deben contener caracteres alfabéticos (A-Z) o (a-z) e incluir letras acentuadas en castellano.
5. El tamaño máximo (contando el espacio de separación entre palabras) es de 15 caracteres y el tamaño mínimo es de 3 caracteres

**SOLUCIÓN**

Como te dije al principio voy a complementar tu expresión regular para cumplir el requerimiento.

La expresión regular que usaré será la siguiente:

```
var patronNombre = /(^[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}([a-zñáéíóú]+){2,})(\s[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}([a-zñáéíóú]+){2,})?$/;
```

La expresión regular anterior establece lo siguiente:

1. `^[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}` Este es el primer elemento del primer grupo de búsqueda, como puedes ver es idéntico al que tenías establecido. Exige que el `string` comience con cualquier valor dentro del rango `[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]`. El `{1}` indica que sólo hay 1 carácter de los que están permitidos.
2. `([a-zñáéíóú]+){2,}` Este es el segundo elemento del primer grupo de búsqueda, también es idéntico al que tenías, pero le he añadido un cuantificador. `[a-zñáéíóú]` Estos son los caracteres permitidos, y el símbolo `+` indica que se puede repetir cualquiera de ellos. El cuantificador `{2,}` indica que debe haber al menos 2 caracteres. Si lo pensamos un momento, esto se traduce en que la palabra tendrá al menos 3 caractéres (sumándole el caracter inicial). Con esto termina el primer grupo de búsqueda.
3. `\s` Este es un valor escapado para indicar un espaciado simple `\s`. Nuestro segundo grupo de búsqueda contiene un elemento de espacio simple siempre como primer carácter.
4. `[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}` Este es el segundo elemento de nuestro segundo grupo de búsqueda, aquí no hay nada nuevo, se repiten las condiciones para el primer grupo de búsqueda.
5. `([a-zñáéíóú]+){2,}` Este es el último elemento de nuestro segundo grupo de búsqueda, también se cumple el criterio que en el primer grupo de búsqueda.
6. Nuestro primer grupo de búsqueda no posee un valor para espaciado simple, esa es la primera diferencia entre el primer y el segundo grupo de búsqueda. Además, le hemos agregado un símbolo `?` al segundo grupo de búsqueda, haciendo este grupo opcional, es decir, puede haber una segunda palabra como puede que no la haya.

De esta forma ya tenemos la expresión regular que podemos usar para validar el campo `input`.

Normalmente, uso el método `trim()` para eliminar los espacios anteriores o posteriores que puedan existir en la cadena de texto. Esto lo hago debido a que hay muchas personas que escriben un espacio al final de cada introducción de texto (usualmente son personas que han tomado algún curso de mecanografía o secretariado, ya que es en esos cursos que se enseña dicha práctica).

Dicho esto, pongo un código para probar la funcionalidad de la validación:

```js
var boton = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn');
var patronNombre = /(^[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}([a-zñáéíóú]+){2,})(\s[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ]{1}([a-zñáéíóú]+){2,})?$/;

boton.forEach(function(element) {
  element.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value.trim();
    var isValid = false;
    if (nombre.length <= 15) {
      if(patronNombre.test(nombre)) {
        isValid = true;
      }
    }
    console.log('isValid: ', isValid);
    window.alert(isValid ? 'El valor es válido': 'El valor no es válido');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
      <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre compuesto" aria-label="Nombre compuesto" aria-describedby="button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button">Validar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Espero que sea la respuesta que estás buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Mauricio, por tomarte el tiempo en responder de forma tan concienzuda. Aunque tu respuesta es 100% válida no me vale particularmente pues, en mi caso, necesito que la validación se realice mediante la expresión regular.

Comment: Muy bien, entiendo, lo que faltaría es la validación del tamaño de la cadena. Como te comenté, no soy experto en `regexp`. Pero creo que se puede solucionar de alguna manera. Si lo consigo actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, yo también estoy con ello pero no consigo cuadrarlo y que funcione.

Comment: Una pregunta, cuando dices *Por último, el nombre, tanto simple como compuesto, no puede sobrepasar de 15 caracteres ni tener menos de tres.* te refieres a que ¿la longitud total de la cadena debe ser de 15 caracteres o cada palabra del nombre compuesto debe tener a lo sumo 15 caracteres?

Comment: En total, Mauricio, entre los dos nombres. Es decir, la longitud de la cadena, incluyendo nombre, o nombre compuesto incluyendo el espacio.